# How can we say "talking past each other"?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I couldn't find an equivalent to the English expression "talking past each other".

What are the expressions (idiomatic or not) that can be used especially in formal situations.

> Talking past each other is an English phrase describing the situation where two or more people talk about different subjects, while believing that they are talking about the same thing.
> (*wikipedia*)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When asking such questions, it is advisable to explain the meaning of the original phrase, especially with idioms like that one.

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the expression "**tenir un dialogue de sourds**".

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialogue_de_sourds))  « Dialogue de sourds » est une expression idiomatique qui désigne une discussion impliquant généralement deux interlocuteurs, qui ne se comprennent pas ou ne s'écoutent pas l'un l'autre en pensant qu'ils conversent ensemble d'un même thème.

*Translation of the above*

A "dialogue de sourds" is an idiomatic phrase used to describe a discussion involving two speakers who do not understand one another or do not listen to one another while thinking that they are talking about one unique question.